# Exception when using MPSImageConvolution

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, gpu, metal

I am trying to use MPSImageConvolution todo some image filtering and keep getting an error: "missing buffer binding at index 1 for wt[0]".
When using the same code with MPSImageLaplacian it is working OK.

This is my code:

```
    let img = UIImage(named: "some-image")!
    // convert to single channel grayscale and scale to half-size
    let image = toGrayscale(cgImage: img.cgImage!, scale: 2)

    let cmdQ: MTLCommandQueue! = device.makeCommandQueue()
    let commandBuffer = cmdQ.makeCommandBuffer()!

    let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device)
    let options: [MTKTextureLoader.Option : Any]? = nil // [ MTKTextureLoader.Option.SRGB : NSNumber(value: false) ]
    let srcTex = try! textureLoader.newTexture(cgImage: image.cgImage!, options: options)

    let lapKernel: [Float] =
    [
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, -4.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0
    ];

    let unsafeArray: UnsafePointer<Float> = UnsafePointer<Float>(lapKernel)

    let desc = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: srcTex.pixelFormat,
                                                              width: srcTex.width,
                                                              height: srcTex.height,
                                                              mipmapped: false)
    desc.usage.formUnion(.shaderWrite)
    let lapTex = device.makeTexture(descriptor: desc)

    //  let lapConv = MPSImageLaplacian(device: device) <-- Using this works fine
    let lapConv = MPSImageConvolution(device: device, kernelWidth: 3, kernelHeight: 3, weights: unsafeArray)
    lapConv.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, sourceTexture: srcTex, destinationTexture: lapTex!)
```

The last line of the above code snippet crashes with the following error:

> validateComputeFunctionArguments:811: failed assertion `Compute Function(k_1x3_R_1x_5y_f): missing buffer binding at index 1 for wt[0].'

Any ideas what could be the issue? besides that I am also using the median filter and threshold filter and all works great...
Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same assertion exception:

`Compute Function(k_1x3_R_1x_5y_f): missing buffer binding at index 1 for wt[0].`

... when using `MPSImageConvolution`. I modified my kernel so that zero values in the matrix became `0.0001`. In your case you could change `lapKernel` to be:

```swift
   let lapKernel: [Float] =
    [
        0.0001, 1.0, 0.0001,
        1.0, -4.0, 1.0,
        0.0001, 1.0, 0.0001
    ]
```

... which I found prevented the assertion exception and hopefully won't significantly alter the functionality of your image filter.

BTW the `;` after `lapKernel` definition in your example is superfluous (apologies if I'm stating the obvious)